# I can't change a title using intelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

How can I change the red title in my IDEA?

Comment: did it work? its two years ago you asked this question, if it works for you please mark my answer as correct, so other people can see it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click to the module.
2. [image: Open Module Settings]
3. Change Name[image: change name]